# Sitecore file drop area destination folder

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I need to know if Sitecore Field **File Drop Area** can have different location set to save uploaded files?

I need to set different folder (media library) because content authors do not have access/rights to publish uploaded files in **File Drop Area**, saved under /System/.

[image]

The best part is that on Production Instance I do not have admin rights to modify security and access for content authors.

Question is: there is an option to set another destination folder on FileDropArea from CMS or only new written custom field can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can change the root folder, but you need to do it in the WebDAV config settings. The setting to change the root FileDropArea location is:

**WebDAV.FileDropAreaMediaLocation**

Its not in the sitecore config by default so add it via an include file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <settings>
            <setting name="WebDAV.FileDropAreaMediaLocation" value="/sitecore/media library/my uploads" />
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

But I don't think you will need too. The files are not uploaded to the System area of the content tree, but the system folder in the Media Library.

[image]

As long as your editors are members of the **sitecore/Authors** role, they should have access to see this folder and its contents.

Comment: Thank you, I will search how to do it, now I know it's possible. Regards access, medilaib/System isn't accessible on Production/Preproduction instances, and I cant change that because I have only developer rights there.

Comment: The setting you need is: WebDAV.FileDropAreaMediaLocation, it looks like its not in the web.config as standard so you can just add it via an include file